# Android listview only first item is getting populated

Tags: android, json, android-listview

Trying to make a listview with data from JSON. phonelist decalred below hold the data parsed from the json.

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> phonelist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

I am doing this in onCreateView of the fragment

```
 for (int i = 0; i < phone.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject c = phone.getJSONObject(i);

                String phId = c.getString("ph_id");
                String phNo = c.getString("ph_no");

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("ph_id", phId);
                map.put("ph_no", phNo);
                phonelist.add(map);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), phonelist,
                R.layout.list_item_phone,
                new String[]{"ph_id", "ph_no"}, new int[]{
                R.id.txtPhoneID, R.id.txtPhoneNum});

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
              //TODO

            }
        });
```

The *phonelist* is getting populated from json and here is its content

```
 [{ph_id=1, ph_no=0120-2550000}, {ph_id=2, ph_no=1860-180-3474}, {ph_id=3, ph_no=0120-4698114}, {ph_id=4, ph_no=0361-2525256}, {ph_id=5, ph_no=033-2525368}, {ph_id=6, ph_no=011-25252525}, {ph_id=7, ph_no=0361-2525257}, {ph_id=8, ph_no=033-2525369}, {ph_id=9, ph_no=011-25252526}, {ph_id=10, ph_no=0361-2525258}, {ph_id=11, ph_no=033-2525370}, {ph_id=12, ph_no=011-25252527}]
    For some reason though, only the first item shows up in the listview.
```

Edit:

Declaration of the phone variable

```
JSONArray phone = null;
```

And then I am getting its value onCreate like below

```
phone = ((JSonArrayParser) getArguments().getParcelable("phoneJsonArray")).getJsonArray();
```

phone.length is showing correct value (12)

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of the phone variable and could you check if phone.length isn't just returning one ?

Comment: Strange. Could you try add notifyDataSetChanged() after setting the adapter?

Comment: Tried. Doesn't work :(

Comment: can you post the two layouts

Answer (score 0):

**HashMap** is specified as key and value, based on webpage @ [Map](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html). Search text for "put (K key, V value)" for reference. In your code:

```
map.put("ph_id", phId);
map.put("ph_no", phNo);
```

I can see only 2 keys are added into this map object, even though you added lots of data from JSON.

As a suggestion, instead of literal string "ph_id" as the key, you can have variable **phId as key** instead, and the v**alue can be phNo**. That can be one code design.

Maybe it's a good idea if you post the SimpleAdapter also, especially in getView().